# SQL: Get last referring and post referring page during a signup process

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to write an efficient SQL query to select 'before' and 'after' pages for  the signup process. I have a solution using for loops which doesn't scale and am hoping to get a SQL native solution.

For a single clientId, I would want to get the latest pages before sign up and after signup (only 1 from each side of the join process).

The join process ALWAYS has `/join/complete`

Input:

```
clientId    time    path
1           0       /page1
1           10      /page2
1           20      /join/<random_token_id>
1           30      /join/<random_token_id>/step2
1           40      /join/complete
1           50      /page2
2           0       /page3
2           10      /join/complete
```

Output

```
ClientId   Before     After
1          /page2     /page2
2          /page3     null
```

I would be grateful if there is an easy solution in SQL. **If it's complex, just leave it out**. I will leave the code running overnight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH lineup AS (
  SELECT clientId, time, path, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY clientId ORDER BY time) pos  
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
), start AS (
  SELECT row.clientId, row.pos FROM (
    SELECT ARRAY_AGG(t ORDER BY pos LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] row
    FROM lineup t WHERE STARTS_WITH(path, '/join/')
    GROUP BY clientId)
), complete AS (
  SELECT clientId, pos FROM lineup WHERE path = '/join/complete'
), before AS (
  SELECT lineup.clientId, path FROM lineup JOIN start 
  ON lineup.clientId = start.clientId AND lineup.pos = start.pos - 1
), after AS (
  SELECT lineup.clientId, path FROM lineup JOIN complete 
  ON lineup.clientId = complete.clientId AND lineup.pos = complete.pos + 1
)
SELECT clientId, before.path AS before, after.path AS after
FROM before FULL OUTER JOIN after USING (clientId)
```

You can test / play with above using dummy data from your question as below

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 clientId, 0 time, '/page1' path UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 10, '/page2' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 20, '/join/<random_token_id>' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 30, '/join/<random_token_id>/step2' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 40, '/join/complete' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 50, '/page2' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 0, '/page3' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 10, '/join/complete' UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 0, '/join/complete' UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 10, '/page4' 
), lineup AS (
  SELECT clientId, time, path, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY clientId ORDER BY time) pos  
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
), start AS (
  SELECT row.clientId, row.pos FROM (
    SELECT ARRAY_AGG(t ORDER BY pos LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] row
    FROM lineup t WHERE STARTS_WITH(path, '/join/')
    GROUP BY clientId)
), complete AS (
  SELECT clientId, pos FROM lineup WHERE path = '/join/complete'
), before AS (
  SELECT lineup.clientId, path FROM lineup JOIN start 
  ON lineup.clientId = start.clientId AND lineup.pos = start.pos - 1
), after AS (
  SELECT lineup.clientId, path FROM lineup JOIN complete 
  ON lineup.clientId = complete.clientId AND lineup.pos = complete.pos + 1
)
SELECT clientId, before.path AS before, after.path AS after
FROM before FULL OUTER JOIN after USING (clientId)
```

with result as

```sql
Row clientId    before      after    
1   1           /page2      /page2   
2   2           /page3      null     
3   3           null        /page4
```